# VBA: Can I use user input to specify which tab to run a VLOOKUP on?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function TwoParVlookup that (you guessed it) runs a Vlookup using two parameters. I'm currently trying to automate the use of this function.
There are several tabs in the worksheet named after a date (Eg: 08.17.16) and the data on each tab are all formatted the same way.

Is it possible to somehow specify which tab to run the TwoParVlookup on? I tried to store user input via InputBox, but the macro wasn't able to recognize it. Here's the code:

```
Sub MakeMattsLifeEasier()

' This macro will use our 2-parameter Vlookup down the column (Date) our user specifies

  Dim myCol As Variant
  Dim myDate As Variant

  myCol = InputBox("Which column shall I populate?")
  myDate = InputBox("Thank you. Which date is this column assigned?")

  Range(myCol & "3").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=TwoParVlookup(myDate!RC[9]:R[9]C[14],6,pGSK.GSK!RC[-2],pGSK.GSK!RC[-1])"
  Range(myCol & "3").Select
  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(myCol & "3:" & myCol & "14"), Type:=xlFillValues


End Sub
```

Note: it's TwoParVlookup(data_range, column_index, parameter1, parameter2)

I was able to specify via InputBox to store a specific column. I think I got a little ahead of myself and tried to accomplish the same using the myDate variable.
For example, I stored "08.16.18" into myDate because there's a tab titled "08.16.18". No such luck.

Comment: this is off topic, but What is a two part v lookup? How does it work? I might have use for something like that.

Comment: @excelguy It works just like v lookup, only it take the two leftmost columns as parameters that need to be fulfilled instead of the one. I actually got it from this example and edited it for my purposes: [link](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/vlookup-multiple-criteria-udf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest making `myDate` and `myCol` both type `String` for clarity and to avoid getting a Date object for the latter

Also, for this line, you need to take your `myDate` variable out of the quotes ""

So:

```
Range(myCol & "3").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=TwoParVlookup(" & myDate & "!RC[9]:R[9]C[14],6,pGSK.GSK!RC[-2],pGSK.GSK!RC[-1])"
```

Answer (score 2):

Control for the input that the users are allowed to populate by using `Application.InputBox`.
 You can find the input 'types' to control for, and other useful info [here!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.InputBox)

Instead of `Range(myCol & 3)`, qualify sheets and use `.Cells(3, myCOl)`.

```
Dim myCol As Integer
myCol = Application.InputBox("Which column shall I populate", Type:=1)

Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, myCol).FormulaR1C1 = ......
```

---

To control for the date input, you can use `Type 8` maybe and have the user select a cell on the sheet they want to run the code on. Something like

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim myDate As Range
Set myDate = Application.InputBox("Select a cell on desired sheet", Type:=8)

Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Set TargetSheet = myDate.Worksheet

MsgBox TargetSheet.Name

End Sub
```

---

Also, you need to code for the option of the user not selecting anything on the `InputBox` and hitting `Cancel` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just concarenate the result from InputBox into the string representing your formula.

```
Sub MakeMattsLifeEasier()

' This macro will use our 2-parameter Vlookup down the column (Date) our user specifies

  Dim myCol As Variant, myDate As Variant

  myCol = InputBox("Which column shall I populate?")
  myDate = InputBox("Thank you. Which date is this column assigned?")

  Range(myCol & "3:" & myCol & "14").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=TwoParVlookup('" & myDate & "'!RC[9]:R[9]C[14], 6, pGSK.GSK!RC[-2], pGSK.GSK!RC[-1])"


End Sub
```

I've added wrapping `'` marks around the worksheet name. If they are needed and not there, the lack of them will break the formula. If they are there and not needed, no harm no foul.

Answer (score 1):

First things first. Let's declare variables as what they actually are, instead of variants. Then let's ensure that the string, which is typed into the input box, is actually a valid date. We do this by converting it to a date; checking its validity; then converting it back to a string of the format you choose.

One problem I noticed was with your FormulaR1C1 line, in that you literally had "myDate" in the formula, instead of inserting the string. This is corrected below. Also note that you do not need to "select" anything; and please ensure that you qualify "Range" references with the actual sheet you want. This will avoid many problems later on.

```
Option Explicit ' Always good to use at the top of your module
Sub MakeMattsLifeEasier()
    ' This macro will use our 2-parameter Vlookup down the column (Date) our user specifies
    Dim myCol As String
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim InputDate As Date
    myCol = InputBox("Which column shall I populate?")
    If Len(myCol) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "You need to type a single column letter."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    DateString = InputBox("Thank you. Which date is this column assigned?")
    On Error GoTo NoDate
    InputDate = CDate(DateString) ' Convert to a date. If this is not a valid date, an error will be thrown.
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset the error handling
    ' Now we've validated that it's a real date. Convert it to your chosen format:
    DateString = Format(InputDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") ' Or however your sheets are named
    '
    With ActiveSheet ' Change ActiveSheet to specify the sheet you actually want
        .Range(myCol & "3").FormulaR1C1 = "=TwoParVlookup(" & DateString & "!RC[9]:R[9]C[14],6,pGSK.GSK!RC[-2],pGSK.GSK!RC[-1])"
        .Range(myCol & "3").AutoFill Destination:=.Range(myCol & "3:" & myCol & "14"), Type:=xlFillValues
    End With
    Exit Sub
NoDate:
    MsgBox "Not a valid date."
End Sub
```